ESRI Search Widget - Edit Arcgis map js search input with multiple sources(version 4.30)
Currently I want to edit the dropdown source, and add a check box to select as shown, instead of displaying it as default. Anyone who knows please help me.


 const searchWidget = new Search({
              view: view,
              allPlaceholder: "Search data",
              includeDefaultSources: false,
              sources: [
                {
                  layer: url1,
                  searchFields: ["ID"],
                  //displayField: "VITRILAPDAT",
                  suggestionTemplate: "ID",
                  exactMatch: false,
                  outFields: ["*"],
                  name: "DHKH",
                  placeholder: "example: 3708",
                },
                {
                  layer: url2,
                  searchFields: ["ID"],
                  suggestionTemplate: "ID",
                  exactMatch: false,
                  outFields: ["*"],
                  name: " DMA",
                  placeholder: "example: 1102",
                },
              ],
            });
            

            // Add the search widget to the top left corner of the view
            view.ui.add(searchWidget, {
              position: "top-right",
            });


No, not using the default Search widget. The ArcGIS JavaScript SDK's widgets use Calcite Design Components for their UI and do not provide a way for you to change which components are used.
You can change the components styling via CSS globals, but not the components themselves.
In the second screenshot, it looks like there's two separate things going on:

A Calcite Dropdown component that contains a Radio Button Group component
A Search widget, whose sources are likely updated based on the Radio Button components selection events (although it's hard to say what's actually going on from just a screenshot -- if the screenshot if from a site please post the URL).

